# login error vsftpd on centos7 azure box

Tags: azure, ftp, centos7, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd on centos 7.1 on an azure box. 
I have edited the file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf so its contents are among others these below

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES 
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I restarted the service and the server too but I can not access ftp still. I login using Filezilla ftp client but I get the error message below

Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command:    USER usr_uat
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ************
Response:   500 OOPS: chroot
Error:          Critical error: Could not connect to server

Using the FTP terminal/shell, the login fails with error '500 OOPS: chroot'

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making sure the permissions are set correctly for that user and the home folder?

Please see the following links

https://www.benscobie.com/fixing-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot/

http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/error-500-oops-vsftpd-refusing-to-run-with-writable-root-inside-chroot-solved/

Comment: i tried a couple of different things, in the end, I had to use the setenforce command to put the SELinux into pemissive mode. that 'solved' the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the notes and links in my article posted at Ask Fedora Forum.  You may need to set SELinux's ftp_home_dir on ON.

```
 > setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

You may also want to add the following setting to the conf file.

```
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

Other suggests are there as well.

[Ask Fedora Forums](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/81001/is-there-a-fix-for-vsftpd-500-login-error-yet/)